# Setting up arango cluster using arangod.conf (/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf) instead of command line options

Tags: arangodb

I was able to start Arango cluster using process mentioned at https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/cluster/deployment/manual-start/

We do not want to pass all the config in the command line each time rather want to make it run from /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf

How do we ensure each CLI option mentioned in above document are taken from the arango config file.

Comment: Did you encounter problems with using a config file, that it only uses some of the parameters?

Answer (score 8):

Command line options and config options are completely equalivalent meaning that you can just transfer them to a config file.

Simple example to translate any arangodb command line option into a config file:

Command line:

```
--server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529
```

Config file:

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529
```

So `server` is referencing to a config group here and `endpoint` is an option.

There is one exception: The database directory can be specified on the command line without explicitly using `--database.directory`.

Full example of the startup of the first agent:

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:5001
authentication = false

[agency]
id = 0
size = 3
supervision = true

[database]
directory=agency1 # better use an absolute path here of course ;)
```

Comment: @CodeMax & mop, -  Have tried all this but that didn't work. Right now config file is not supporting what we can do from CLI. Even ArangoDB folks said that either use custom scripts or DCOS to install.

Comment: arangodbs config maps 1:1 from the commandline. see https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Configuration/index.html for more details. Not all combinations of settings may be usefull however.

Comment: @dothebart : Have tried it but it doesn't work. Custom scripts needs to be written to handle the cluster using processes (CLI). Config file doesn't accept everything at the moment.

Comment: except for `--help` and `--config` everything can be specified in a configuration file. If the parameter isn't known, arangod will abort the start with an appropriate error message naming the non-understood param. You have to make sure the param ends up in the right section, where `--section.param value` translates to `[section]\nparam=value`